# Folland's Real Analysis, Theorem 0.3

Tags: logic, set-theory, well-orders

The theorem 0.3 in Folland's Real analysis book, proves that Zorn's Lemma implies Well-Ordering.

In the theorem, we construct on any set $X$ a collection $\mathcal{W}$ of all well-orderings of subsets of $X$. In the collection $\mathcal{W}, (E_{1},\leq_{1})\leq (E_{2},\leq_{2})$ if

1. $E_{1}\subset E_{2}$ and $\leq_{1}$ agrees with $\leq_{2}$ on $E_{1}$.
2. If $x\in E_{2}\setminus E_{1}$, then $y\leq_{2}x$ for all $y\in E_{1}$.

I was able to show that any collection $\{(E_{\alpha},\leq_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ which is linearly ordered, then the ordering $(E,\leq_{\mathcal{P}})$ where $E = \bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}$ and ordering between any two elements is done using the fact that any two elements lie in some $E_{\alpha}$ and I was able to prove that this way of ordering is well defined.

But I am stuck at proving that $(E,\leq_{\mathcal{P}})$ is well-ordered.

Comment: Suppose there is some non-empty subset of $E$ without a least element.  What goes wrong?

Comment: Oh! Yeah, thanks, I got it. So we basically go to an element, $E_{\alpha}$ and use well-ordering property and properties of ordering on $\mathcal{W}$ to derive a contradiction, right?

Comment: Exactly! I think you have it now.

Comment: It might be instructive to show first that $A$ (the indexing of the chain) has to be well-ordered itself.

Comment: Hello Asaf, I didn't quite understand why I need to show that $A$ is well-ordered. I think I am able to show that $(E,\leq_{\mathcal{P}})$ without using the fact that $A$ is well-ordered. 

Is the fact that $A$ is well-ordered needed anywhere else?